# statement.isClose() is throwing an IllegalAccess Exception because the statement is close?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I have the code below. Fairly standard stuff. However, I'm getting illegal access exceptions on the if(!stmt.isClose()) line... the error indicates that it's because the statement is closed. Isn't that the point of that method call? Anyone have some thoughts on this?

```
Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
try {
    stmt.executeUpdate(updateQuery1);
    stmt.executeUpdate(updateQuery2);
    stmt.executeUpdate(updateQuery3);
    conn.commit();
    try {
        if (!stmt.isClosed()) {
            stmt.close();
        }
        if (!conn.isClosed()) {
            conn.close();
        }
    } catch (Throwable ignored) {
} catch(Throwable ignored) {
}
```

`499285 java.lang.IllegalAccessError: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.isClosed()Z
499286   at com.millennialmedia.enterprise.services.impl.CampaignUtilServiceImpl.resetExceptionCampaign(CampaignUtilServiceImpl.java:80)
499287   at com.millennialmedia.rest.services.CampaignUtilRESTService$1.process(CampaignUtilRESTService.java:55)
499288   at com.millennialmedia.rest.services.CampaignUtilRESTService$1.process(CampaignUtilRESTService.java:49)
499289   at com.millennialmedia.services.util.Processor.doProcess(Processor.java:98)
499290   at com.millennialmedia.rest.services.CampaignUtilRESTService.resetExceptionCampaign(CampaignUtilRESTService.java:49)
499291   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
499292   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
499293   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
499294   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
499295   at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
499296   at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchPro
499297   at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
499298   at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
499299   at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
499300   at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
499301   at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
499302   at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
499303   at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
499304   at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
499305   at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
499306   at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
499307   at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
499308   at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
499309   at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
499310   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
499311   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
499312   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
499313   at com.millennialmedia.instrumentation.MethodInvocationFilter._doFilter(MethodInvocationFilter.java:20)
499314   at com.millennialmedia.instrumentation.MethodInvocationFilter.doFilter(MethodInvocationFilter.java:31)
499315   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
499316   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
499317   at com.millennialmedia.session.BaseAuthenticatedUserFilter.doFilter(BaseAuthenticatedUserFilter.java:249)
499318   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
499319   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
499320   at com.millennialmedia.session.HibernateSessionRequestFilter.doFilter(HibernateSessionRequestFilter.java:57)
499321   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
499322   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
499323   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
499324   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
499325   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
499326   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
499327   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
499328   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
499329   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
499330   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
499331   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)`

Comment: did you disable the auto commit mode ?? commit() method should be used only when auto-commit mode has been disabled.

Comment: @chaitanya10 The answer to that is in the code.

Answer (score 5):

I know this post is outdated, but since I ran into this issue today, I thought I could spare others some time.
The reason that you get this error is that you use an pre Java 6 (and pre JDBC-4) Tomcat-Version, where

```
java.sql.Statement.isClosed()
```

is **not** part of the interface:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html

but in Java 6, it is:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#isClosed%28%29

See method-visibility of isClosed() here

http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/tomcat/dbcp/6.0.20/dbcp-6.0.20.jar!/org/apache/tomcat/dbcp/dbcp/DelegatingStatement.class?classDetails=ok

vs. here:

http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-dbcp/7.0.23/tomcat-dbcp-7.0.23.jar!/org/apache/tomcat/dbcp/dbcp/DelegatingStatement.class?classDetails=ok

The comment on isClose() of the current DelegatingStatement says:

```
/*
* Note was protected prior to JDBC 4
* TODO Consider adding build flags to make this protected unless we are
*      using JDBC 4.
*/
public boolean isClosed() throws SQLException {
    return _closed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are even testing it. The statement cannot possibly be closed at this point, so don't test it, just close it. Ditto the connection. In fact both those close methods are specified to do nothing if already closed.

Don't gild the lily.

Comment: Well, it is closed at this point apparently, which is why I get the exception :) I test because it's safer, for instance if the underlying connection goes away.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the implementation of the PreparedStatement that your datasource is providing you.
If you take a look to the traces you provided, you can see this:

**499285 java.lang.IllegalAccessError: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.isClosed()Z**

This means that the implementation of the PreparedStatement you are used is an instance of class org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingStatement. If you take a look to version [1.2.2](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-1.2.2/org/apache/commons/dbcp/DelegatingStatement.html#isClosed()), method **isClosed()** is protected so any attempt to access to this method will cause a java.lang.IllegalAccessError. The rest of versions of this library (1.3 and upper) turned this modifier up public so you only have to change your library version to solve this problem.